# Convert all elements to atribuites

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my sample XML, i would like to transform all elements to atributes using xslt. I am new to xslt and so far i have solution to convert person's elements to attributes:

```
<xsl:template match="person">
    <person>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </person>
</xsl:template>
```

But i have problem with concat it together with converting squad elements to attributes.

example input:

```
<squad>
    <competitionId>12345asdf</competitionId>
    <contestantId>1234avhj</contestantId>
    <person>
        <name>Abc</firstName>
        <lastName>Fgh</lastName>
        <middleName></middleName>
        <id>dfghfgdhjgfhjk3425dz</id>
    </person>
    <person>
        <firstName>Dcb</firstName>
        <lastName>Has</lastName>
        <middleName></middleName>
        <id>dfghfgdhjgfhjk1234dz</id>
    </person>
</squad>
```

example output:

```
 <squad contestantId="1234avhj" competitionId="12345asdf">
        <person id="dfghfgdhjgfhjk3425dz" firstName="Abc" middleName="" lastName="Fgh"/>
        <person id="dfghfgdhjgfhjk1234dz" firstName="Dcb" middleName="" lastName="Has"/>
 </squad>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having templates matching specific elements, have a more generic template, but you will need to make sure only child elements which have no child elements themselves are converted to attributes.

Try this template instead

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[not(*)]">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[*]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```